# How to create different outputs with an item of a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list with countries with country as items and two variables. For the variables, I would like to loop through the list of countries that create different outputs according to its specified country. Now I get only 3 lines per country. I want to have 3 lines * length of my list.

Now I have to specify one country at a time, while I want to pass an entire list. To illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Sales', sheet_name='unique enroll- Dataset')

#What I do now:
country = 'Arabian Emirates'    

#What I want to do: 
country_lst = [ 'Arabian Emirates', 'Argentina', 'Australia']

def country(country):
     for country in country_lst:
         return country
```

Variables:

```
Renewal1 = df[(df["Country2"] == country) & (df["Quarter"] == "2000-Q4")]

Renewal2 = df[(df["Country2"] == country) & (df["Quarter"] == "2000-Q4")& (df["License Model"].isin(['A'])
```

Output:

```
print("These numbers are for: " + country)
print("#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: " + str(Renewal1["Count_Contract"].sum()))
print("# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: " + str(Renewal2["Count_Contract"].sum()))
```

Output now (the last item of the list):

```
These numbers are for: Arabian Emirates
#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: 5
# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: 3
```

Desired Output:

```
These numbers are for: Arabian Emirates
#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: 5
# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: 3

These numbers are for: Argentina
#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: 6
# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: 1

These numbers are for: Australia
#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: 1
# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do the job:

```
def country_data(country):
    Renewal1 = df[(df["Country2"] == country) & (df["Quarter"] == "2000-Q4")]
    Renewal2 = df[(df["Country2"] == country) & (df["Quarter"] == "2000-Q4")& (df["License Model"].isin(['A'])
    return (str(Renewal1["Count_Contract"].sum()),str(Renewal2["Count_Contract"].sum()))

for c in country_lst:
    cd = country_data(c)
    print("These numbers are for: " + c)
    print("#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: " + cd[0])
    print("# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: " + cd[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you want to do for each country should be inside the for loop:

```
def country(country_lst):
     for country in country_lst:
         Renewal1 = df[(df["Country2"] == country) & (df["Quarter"] == "2000-Q4")]
         Renewal2 = df[(df["Country2"] == country) & (df["Quarter"] == "2000-Q4")& (df["License Model"].isin(['A'])
         print("These numbers are for: " + country)
         print("#1 of Renewals per sub for Q4: " + str(Renewal1["Count_Contract"].sum()))
         print("# Non SCE of Renewals per sub for Q4: " + str(Renewal2["Count_Contract"].sum()))
```